# Magento 2.2.8 not saving HTML head

Tags: html, head

Just upgraded to 2.2.8. Trying to add something into HTML head section, but it does not go to the front-end. At the same time enabling "Display Demo Store Notice" did work.

Tried cleaning & flushing Magento 2 cache, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Is your site in production mode?Are you using any third party cache?

Comment: No 3rd party caches. The site is just stock Magento 2.2.8 with sample data.

Comment: So are you adding in admin or in code?Either your instance is in production or developent mode?

Comment: In admin back-office -> Content -> Configuration -> site edit -> HTML head.

Comment: Tried both development and production mode.